# Why is a signed int is auto-casted to an unsigned int if the computer is "copying bits"?

Tags: c, casting, int, bit, unsigned

I'm recently learning C, and there is something that I cannot understand.

Here is the example,

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = a;
```

In this example, the book says,

```
  "a is auto-casted to 'unsigned int' and then assigned to 'unsigned int b'."
```

but... why? I mean

'int a' is -1, so it's bit string is supposed to be

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

In Computer's point of view, all it has to do is **just copying the bits to unsigned int b**

there's no need to convert 'signed int' to 'unsigned int'  !

I can't understand, why they auto-cast 'signed int' to 'unsigned int' before copy the bits?

Comment: well, consider what happens with your code. `-1` is an impossible value for an unsigned variable. So what SHOULD happen if you assign an impossible value?

Comment: `b` is `unsigned int` and you are copying those bits over to it from `a`. There really is no change to the bits, only the way they are handled in as an unsigned value instead of signed, and the highest bit no longer is a sign bit but part of the number.

Comment: When you do signed/unsigned casting, the bit pattern stored in memory *doesn't actually change*. It's just interpreted differently.

Comment: The bits don't change, what change is how you read the bits when type change.

Comment: What book is this please? And is that a direct quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... when you initialize an `unsigned int` object with`signed int` value, there's definitely a need to convert `unsigned int` to `signed int`. This is exactly what you asked the language to do by mixing these two different types in an initialization. When you initialize an object of type `T` with a value of different type `U`, type `U` has to be implicitly *converted* to type `T`. (Or an error has to be reported, if there's no appropriate conversion.) There's no way around it. There's no way to "mate" two different types besides a conversion.

Also, there's no such thing as "bit copying". I don't know why your book decided to invent such concept in this case. When a `singed int` value is converted to `unsigned int` type, the signed value is transformed in accordance with the rules of modulo arithmetic. That's what happens in your case. On 2's-complement platforms the transformation is conceptual, meaning that the bit-representation of the value does not change (this is what apparently meant by "bit copying").

Comment: So.. '=' is not just copying the bits :)  thank you!

Comment: @S. Patrick: Well, in practice it will probably boil down to "just copying the bits" in compiled code. But language itself does not describe it in such terms. Language describes it in terms of higher-level concepts, like "conversion" and "modulo arithmetic". But on many (or most) modern hardware platforms these concepts make no impact on the actual machine code. They dissipate without a trace.

Comment: in ones complement (where the ranges overlap) positive signed integers also have the same representation as unsigned,  I think this overlap is required by the standards

Answer (score 3):

C assigns values to variables by value, not by representation. `-1` is obviously not representable in an unsigned type, so a conversion must be effected. Here the rule (from signed type to unsigned type) is a conversion "modulo", thus `-1` ends up to be the maximum value of the unsigned type.

If you want to "assign" by representation, you would to have to use a copy function, such as `memcpy`, but be aware that this might lead to undefined behavior if the original bit pattern is not supported by the target type.

Also, for the vocabulary, in C we are speaking of "conversions". What you have here is an implicit conversion. Explicit conversion are also called "casts".

Your book doesn't seem to be aware of all of that, and applies bizarre vocabulary. Probably it would be better if you'd get yourself a new and better one.

Answer (score 1):

Too many programmers are educated in such a way that they write programs assuming all negative numbers are represented as 2's complement and assume signed/unsigned conversion are bitwise copy.

However language has no intention to force every computer/compiler to represent negative numbers in exactly this way, although it's popular.

C relaxed the requirement of the representation of negative number to give more flexibility of implementation, but at the same time made the "conventional" 2's-complement-bitwise-copy type conversion a part of the standard so that most of the time, those false assumptions does not cause problems.

Comment: thank you! I thought they are running in the same way.